# Setting a joint in the right pose

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

---

### Updated description:

I would like to perform a rotation around a local Y-axis that points to another direction than the global Y-axis.

Global coordinate system is: span( (1,0,0); (0,1,0); (0,0,1) )

Local coordinate system shall be: span( (1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(2),0); (1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2),0) ; (0,0,1) )

Now the desired rotation has to be around the new Y-axis (1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2),0). As you can see below, when I add a rotation to the model pose, the sensor pose or the pose of the link, no rotation to my new coordinate system is added. Do I have to use the joint of type "revolute2" to add the "static" rotation around the Z-axis before performing the rotation around the "new / local" Y-axis? Is there another possibility?

---

Old description:
I have to do a very simple operation: a child link (sensor) of a model shall do half of a rotation (SetJointPosition, 0 to -pi) around the parent link (box). I have a model for this with a parent and a child link. Everything is all right as long as the joints pose has no rotation in it.

```
<model name="box">
  <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
  <static>false</static>
  <link name="link">
    <collision name="collision">...</collision>
    <visual name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>1 1 1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <link name="link2">
   <pose>0.0 0.0 0.51 0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
    <sensor name="raysensor" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <ray>...</ray>
    </sensor>
  </link>
  <joint name="my_joint" type="revolute">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0.785</pose>
    <parent>link</parent>
    <child>link2</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
    </axis>
  </joint>
</model>
```

[image: Picture of the joint]

The translation works. If I set an offset in x, y or z-coordinate the joint is shifted to the requested point. A rotation isn't done.

I tried to fix this with turning the whole model, but even this failed:
[image: Turning the whole model]

What can I do to bring my joint in the right position?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3878/setting-a-joint-in-the-right-pose/) by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found out, that it is just a problem with the visualisation of the joint... the rotation is done correctly, although the joint axes are wrong...

The added rotation to the model turns the model and the sensor (and the joint, but it is not shown) I expected that the red x-axis points in the rotated direction...

[image: image description]

Here you can see the correct rotation -pi/2 (although the joint axis are not in the right positions)

[image: image description]

I want to add, that it is not enough to just rotate the sensor link!

[image: image description]  [image: image description]

I think this might be connected with this [bug](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/494/make-joint-axis-reference-frame-relative)?!

---

Originally posted by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) with karma: 67 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0